# How do I integrate $\sqrt{4-\sqrt{x}}$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals

I'm trying to integrate $\int\sqrt{4 - \sqrt{x}} \, dx$.  I thought I should do a $u$-sub with $u=\sqrt{x}$, or maybe $u=4-\sqrt{x}$, but then I get $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ or $du=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \, dx$ which isn't part of what I'm trying to integrate.

This is in the section of the book on u-subs so I'm sure we're supposed to do a u-sub, but I don't know what else to try.  Please help!

Comment: I've added some formatting, you should hit the "edit" button and take a look at how I did it so that in the future you can format your math correctly! :)

Comment: Hint: When you do these substitutions, try to express $dx$ in terms of ($u$ and) $du$, not the other way around. For example, if you make the substitution $u = \sqrt{x}$ in some problem (not this one), then rather than $du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} dx$, you probably want to notice that $x = u^2$ and therefore $dx = 2u du$. Basically, do what it takes to write your original integral entirely in terms of $u$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Thanks ShreevatsaR, that was the bit I was not understanding.  Marvis's answer makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I = \int \sqrt{4-\sqrt{x}} dx$$
Set $4 - \sqrt{x} = t$ i.e. $x = (4-t)^2$. We then have
$$I = \int \sqrt{t} 2 (t-4)dt$$
Now you should be able to integrate this. Move your mouse over the gray area for the complete answer.

> \begin{align}I & = \int \sqrt{t} 2 (t-4)dt = 2 \int t^{3/2} dt - 8 \int t^{1/2} dt = 2 \dfrac{t^{5/2}}{5/2} - 8 \dfrac{t^{3/2}}{3/2} + \text{constant}\\& = \dfrac45 (4-\sqrt{x})^{5/2} - \dfrac{16}3 (4-\sqrt{x})^{3/2} + \text{constant}\end{align}

Comment: That was a tricky substitution, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To integrate $\int\sqrt{4-\sqrt{x}}\, dx$, define $J=\int\sqrt{4-\sqrt{x}}\, dx$. Let $x=u^2$. Then $J=\int 2u\sqrt{4-u}\, du$. Now, let $u=4\sin^2 t$, then $J=2\int4\sin^2 t \cdot 2\cos t \cdot 8\sin t \cos t \, dt$. Hence $J=128\int (\sin t)^3(\cos t)^2 \, dt$. Consider $S=\int (\sin t)^3(\cos t)^2 \, dt$: note $S=\int \sin t (1-\cos^2 t)\cos^2 t\, dt$. Hence $S=\int \sin t \cos^2 t \, dt-\int \sin t \cos^4 t \, dt $.

Hence $S=-\frac{1}{3}\cos^3 t+\frac{1}{5}\cos^5 t$. Note that $\cos t=\sqrt{1-\frac{u}{4}}$. And then convert the expression $-\frac{1}{3}\cos^3 t+\frac{1}{5}\cos^5 t$ into a function of $x$.